# How to get value of textbox in code-behind which was set by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom, code-behind

I'm using ASP.net and setting the value of a textbox with Javascript. When I go to save the contents of the page I am unable to get the value of the textbox, it just comes back as nothing.

I have tried setting the value using value, innertext and innerhtml and unable to get the value from any of them.
Setting using JS:

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtNettWeight.ClientID %>').innerText = NettWeight;
```

On Save:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNettWeight.Text))
    {                                      sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetWeight", Convert.ToDecimal(txtNettWeight.Text));
    }
```

Comment: What is the markup you use for the TextBox?

Answer (score -1):

try using single qoutes

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtNettWeight.ClientID %>').value = "Heloo world";
```

---

This works for me,

**Html Markup:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNettWeight" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<div id="test">test<div>
```

**Client-side:**

```
$("#test").on('click', function () {
     document.getElementById('<%= txtNettWeight.ClientID %>').value = "Heloo world";
  });
```

**Code behind:**

```
string getValue=txtNettWeight.Text;
```

Comment: As I said; I've tried the .value property. I have looked at the object using IE developer tools and the value does not show as a property, but is shown on screen.

Comment: @ downvoter: do care about comment , if you downvote add reason

Comment: This is essentially exactly what I already have and it doesn't work.